# Logistic regression on tic tac toe dataset

Tags: dataset, machine-learning, regression

I want to implement Logistic Regression in Java and apply it to the [tic-tac-toe dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Tic-Tac-Toe+Endgame).

I am considering each instance as a state of the board. so each instance has 9 features. for example `{x,o,o,x,o,b,x,x,o}` is a instance which represent this board:

```
x o o
x o b
x x o
```

so we have 9 features which can take one of `{x,o,b}` values.

I have heard of something like distributed representation which is used in these cases, according to which we have the following representation for each value:

```
x -> 1 0 0
b -> 0 1 0 
o -> 0 0 1
```

but I don't know how to apply logistic regression to it.
Is there any idea how we can represent this dataset for the logistic regression algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a distributed representation, you would create new instances with 27 (binary) features. The first 3 features represent one of `x, o, b` being true on the first square, and the next 3 for the second square, so on. For each group of 3, an instance will have exactly one `1` and the rest `0`. The label would be whether the `x` player won or not, as given in the dataset.

Then you would just run logistic regression on the vectors of 27 features, one vector for each instance, and it will try to match the label for each vector.